# Bukkit / Java customisable percentage chances

Tags: java, random, probability, bukkit

everyone. I'm trying to make a crates plugin in Bukkit (that doesn't really matter), and I'm having trouble with the random chance drawing.
Since everything is customizable (You can create an indefinite amount of prizes with whatever chance you want), I'm finding it difficult to make the percentage drawing. 
This is my code right now:

```
            for (DoubleStack ds : items.values()) {
                double chance = ds.getChance();
                p.sendMessage(chance + " " + random + " " + ds.getItemStack().getType());
                if (random >= chance) {
                    p.getInventory().addItem(ds.getItemStack());
                    break;
                }
            }
```

A DoubleStack is just a class I made that stores the item and the chance of getting it.
As you can see, the method I am using is buggy, as the chances aren't realistic, and you have a chance of getting multiple items (I don't want this)

So, how would I be able to do this?

Thanks!

Also, I have looked at all the other probability threads, but they don't cover NOT KNOWING specifically what the probabilities are, they just do things like:

```
int x = new Random().nextInt(100);
if(x <= 10 && x >= 20) {
   doSomething(); }
//Repeats with different numbers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (DoubleStack ds : items.values()) {
    int random = new Random().nextInt(100);    
    int chance = ds.getChance(); // Must be in percentage
    if (random < chance) {
        p.getInventory().addItem(ds.getItemStack());
        break;
    }
}
```

To always get a reward (chances must add up to 100):

```
int random = new Random().nextInt(100); 
int counter = 0;   
for (DoubleStack ds : items.values()) {
    int chance = ds.getChance();
    if (random < (chance + counter) && random >= counter) {
        p.getInventory().addItem(ds.getItemStack());
        break;
    }
    counter+=chance;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot better than before, thanks, but sometimes I get absolutely no reward.

Comment: I edited my answer, if this solved your question please click on the check mark to accept it.

Comment: I still don't always get a prize, here's an example config file to help figure out why
https://hastebin.com/ofowibatax.css
In this example, I only get chestplates